# Prevent cheating in a timed online quiz

Tags: javascript, php, anti-cheat

My company regularly run competitions on the internet. These consist of simple multiple choice  quizzes, where the fastest person to complete the quiz wins a prize.

Recently we've been having big problem with cheaters (a lot of sub one second entries that would be impossible to complete manually). The time is calculated server side, so the cheater can't be manipulating the times directly. The only feasible way to cheat would be to write a script to automatically fill in and submit the quiz.

We've already implemented the following to try and combat this:

- Limit the user to one entry (by checking IP and asking for email address)
- randomly take questions from a pool (unfortunately each quiz has to be translated, so the actual pool size is quite small due to our limited translation resources)
- randomize question and answer order
- randomize quiz element class names and ids

Even with all of the techniques above, we're still getting people who manage to cheat.

As a last resort, we're considering replacing the quiz text with images, and randomizing the image names, but this would be a nightmare for accessibility and could still feasibly be cheated by using image comparison. Hence, we really want to avoid this if at all possible.

So I was wondering if anybody here had any ideas of how to combat this?

Comment: Captcha should do the trick!  http://www.captcha.net/

Comment: Simple, sessions and tokens.

Comment: Multiple people can be on the same IP. Just an FYI.

Comment: Have you considered moving to a text-based answer (writing a short response)?  It would take you more time to read the answers but would make instant-answer very difficult

Comment: [Have a look at this](http://phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html) this is what I use (Sessions/tokens) works quite well. You just need to modify it for your needs. Plus the use of a DB would also prove to be beneficial.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This doesn't stop someone from writing a script to answer the questions, I could program something in the browser (which has sessions enabled) to whizz through the quiz despite the form tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe load the next **Random** question with AJAX only after the previous question get answered. I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work, because if a script was doing it the question before it would have been answered... just that it was answered very quickly!

Comment: If the next question that will come is in Random order i don't think there is a way you can cheat

Comment: Also you could make a login system so people only submit their answers once

Comment: Sadly I think you could still cheat, because if you've taken the quiz before, then you can know (and record) all of the questions and possible answers.  If you're desperate to cheat then a script can just answer the questions according to what is being shown.  I guess the only way to make this slightly less likely would be to restrict the questions to a "pool" of questions.  If you only show 10 questions and there are 30 possible questions, then it would take many attempts at taking the quiz to get all of the questions, answers and correct answers.  Just a thought :)

Comment: what would you do about people just signing up for a second account?

Comment: It's not a super correct or bulletproof answer just for discussion food for thought :P You could have users log in with their Facebook Account and decline profiles created few days ago. It's possible, is it right? i don't know!